# How to pass from {Probability density function, convolution} to {Probability density function, characteristic function}?

Tags: density-function, convolution, characteristic-function

In Forsman, W.C. (1986) "Polymers in solution: theoretical considerations and newer methods of characterization", Springer, New York. 
https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780306421464 page 24, it states:

it follows directly from $P(X=x_1+x_2) = P_1(x_1) * P_2(x_2)$ (*: convolution) that the characteristic function of $P(X=x_1+x_2)$ is just the product of the characteristic functions of the $P_i(X_i)$.

I understand the following:

p(x+y)=(p_x * p_y)(τ) ≡ p_x(τ) * p_y(τ) ≡ ∫p_x (t) p_y (τ-t)dt.

But I can't establish the connection in "it follows directly from" part.

Namely, passage from {Probability density function, convolution} to {Probability density function, characteristic function}. Can someone detail the "follows directly" part?

In Battin 1999, "An Introduction to the Mathematics and Methods of Astrodynamics, Revised Edition (AIAA Education)" page 726, it is written:

$$ \phi_{X+Y}(t) = E(e^{it(X+Y)})= E(e^{itX}e^{itY}) 
=E(e^{itX})E(e^{itY}) (since X and Y are independent)
=\phi_{X}(t)\phi_{Y}(t) $$

So, why convolution is ever mentioned? Why that messy stuff there?

**What I found:**
**1.** http://elib.sfu-kras.ru/bitstream/handle/2311/20241/fateev.pdf

It is known that the characteristic function of the sum of independent
random variables is equal to the the (Erdogan: Two "the" here; smt is missing) characteristic functions of the terms, while the density of the probability distribution of the sum is the convolution operation using the probability density function of terms.

**2.** Whuber's idea:

$$ P(X=x_1+x_2) = P_1(x_1) * P_2(x_2) $$
*(Here,* $x_1$ *and* $x_2$ *are two random variables;* $X$ *is the sum of the random variables.)*

Now, take the Fourier transformation of each side,
$$\mathcal{F} ( P(X=x_1+x_2) ) = \mathcal{F} (P_1(x_1) * P_2(x_2)) $$

Apply "Fourier transformation turns convoluiton into multiplication":

$$\mathcal{F} ( P(X=x_1+x_2) ) = \mathcal{F} (P_1(x_1)) \mathcal{F} (P_2(x_2)) $$

Apply the inverse Fourier transformation:

$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F} ( P(X=x_1+x_2) ) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F} (P_1(x_1)) \mathcal{F} (P_2(x_2))) $$

**The remaining issues in my mind:**
**1.** Does the applying F^-1 and F consecutively may result in direct cancellation, or with 1/(2Pi) constant?
**2.** On the right hand side, there is $$ \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F} (P_1(...)) \mathcal{F} (P_2(...))) $$, but not 
$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F} (P_1(...)P_2(...)) $$. What about the cancellation on the right hand side?

**3. (neat explanation of the problem)** I know "the characteristic function of the random variable $x$ is the inverse Fourier transformation of the pdf of the random variable $x$ (when $$ \sqrt{2\pi} $$ coefficient ignored)".

$$ P(X=x_1+x_2) = P_1(x_1) * P_2(x_2) $$

Take the inverse Fourier transformation of each side:

$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1} (P(X=x_1+x_2)) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}( P_1(x_1) * P_2(x_2) )$$

$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1} (P(X=x_1+x_2)) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}( P_1(x_1)) \mathcal{F}^{-1}( P_2(x_2) )$$

$$ \phi_{x_1+x_2}(t) = \phi_{x_1}(t)\phi_{x_2}(t) $$

So, "the characteristic function of $X=x_1+x_2$ is the product of the characteristic functions of the $X_i$" is OK. But, what Forsman says is "the characteristic function of $P(X=x_1+x_2)$ is just the product of the characteristic functions of the $P_i(X_i)$ (i.e. the following expression)" is somewhat misleading?

$$ \phi_{P(X = x_1 + x_2)}(t) = \phi_{P(x_1)}(t)\phi_{P(x_2)}(t) $$

By the above last paragraph, I hope I fully depicted the problem at last.

Comment: It seems what Fateev forget is "product of" in consecutive two "the"s

Comment: "Follows directly" refers implicitly to a basic theorem of Fourier analysis, which is that [the Fourier transform converts convolution into multiplication.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)  The characteristic function is (a version of) the Fourier transform.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your help. I applied your idea, and proceeded a little bit more. I     learnt Fourier series and trans 20 years ago, but not applied it since then and forget naturally.

Comment: The last equation you write down makes no sense because all three subscripts are *numbers* rather than distributions or random variables.

Comment: @whuber When I write X=x1+x2, the RHS "x1+x2" is written as subscript wrongly; it is due to my bad Latex knowledge.  The RHS "x1+x2" must be at the same level with "X=". Also, x1 and x2 are random variables. X is the sum of these random variables.

Comment: That still makes no sense: the basic problem is the appearance of "$P$" in all the subscripts.